# Spark principle is "send code to the data". What does this mean?

Tags: apache-spark

Spark principle is "send code to the data". What does this mean? Why this is better and more efficient than "send data to code" in Spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually Spark deals with large amount of data and does CPU intensive operations on it e.g. transformation or machine learning. It needs to keep the data in memory. Memory on a single machine is limited. So Spark loads data in multiple nodes, and sends the algorithm to those machines to be executed on the data.
In addition, Spark is also utilizing CPUs of 'n' nodes rather than just one.
Such data us usually organized as keys. E.g. we need to calculate accounts data of large number of customers. These can be calculated in parallel on separate nodes. So there is a big performance gain.
Once all the calculation is done on the nodes, the final solution from each node can be collected on your machine or better, if it is v large, write to output files on NAS or HDFS.
See [image] to get an idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you send the data to the code, then your edge node is

1. reading all the data
2. processing / filtering all the data
3. writing the results somewhere

The alternative is for the edge node to send the code *to* the data

1. writing the code to the data nodes
2. waiting for the data nodes to perform the processing / filtering
3. waiting for confirmation that the data has been successfully written

The reason that scales better is simple, there are **more** data nodes than edge nodes **and** *locality* of data means better performance.

Comment: "Locality of data" means partitions are each stored in a worker's memory and worker receives the disitrbutable command (map, filter, filterMap...) to process?

Comment: @Barcelona The partitions might have spilled to a worker's disk, but regardless the filtering and mapping takes place on the worker - instead of requiring the data first be read from the worker to the edge node (sending data to code).